# Localizable.strings (Base) file strings not read by other language set in iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, localizable.strings

I've implemented multilingual in my app and having multiple `Localizable.strings` files created.

[image]

I have all strings key and value in `Localizable.strings (Base)` file, as its default file read from all other languages if perticular string missing in specific language string file e.g. `Localizable.strings (Japanese)` and some strings are missing in `Japanese` file so I expecting to get string translation from `Base`.

But it doesn't happen, thats my problem.

Comment: Is there are more than 1 language string in Base string file or only strings for Japanese?

Comment: Base string has all english strings translations and if debugger don't find string in Japanese then it should pick by default from Base file.

Comment: Yes it has to happen like this. What string you are seeing now?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal I can see only key which I'm trying to access when my iPhone language is Japanese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue and applied this solution:

1. Create new default String localize file for English (`DefaultEnglish.strings`)
   E.g: `"hello_key" = "Hello"`
2. Add other language support to `Localizable.strings` file
   E.g: Japanese string: `"hello_key" = "こんにちは"`

[image]

3. Create String `extension`

   ```
   extension String {

   func localizedStringKey(bundle _: Bundle = .main, tableName: String = "Localizable") -> String {
       return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: tableName, value: "\(NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: "DefaultEnglish", bundle: .main, value: self, comment: ""))", comment: "")
   }     }
   ```
4. and set string `"hello_key".localizedStringKey()`

Comment: Btw, it's better to check value, returned by NSLocalizedString, and if we don't have such key - we should take some actions, for example - write a log message.

Answer (score 2):

No, **The base localisation file is used when there is no specific localised version of the file available.** 
E.g. if your app has a base localisation of English and you add French localisation, languages other than French will get the English values.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstring) for `NSLocalizedString(key,comment)` is pretty clear -

> The initial value for `key` in the strings file will be `key`. Use the
>   `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` macro to specify another value for
>   key.

What else would you expect it to return? The code simply looks up the key in a dictionary.  It has no idea what message is associated with the key, let alone how to translate that message into Russian.

Answer (score 1):

When localising an an app, there's no need to use a `Base` `Localizable.strings` file.

Localise your strings as follows…

```
NSLocalizedString("DISMISS_BUTTON", value: "Press To Dismiss", comment: "Button used to dismiss the payment screen")
```

Then `key` (the first parameter) is used to look up in a `Localizable.strings` for a given language. If it's not found, it will use the `value` parameter in the string as a fallback.

If you use Xcode's **Export For Localization…**, the xliff file will include the keys from all your `NSLocalizedString`s

The only time you'll need a `Base` `Localizable.strings` is for keys that don't appear as a string in your source, .e.g.

```
let localisableName = "LAYOUT_NAME_" + name.uppercased()
NSLocalizedString(localisableName)
```

In this case, you should add

```
"LAYOUT_NAME_WHATEVER" = "Whatever";
```

to your `base` file, and it will also be included in the generated xliff